# Create a trigger annually in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, execute

I need to create a trigger annually and updates profit using mysql..
The table related to these question is ,

```
create table annual_document(
  documment_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  income decimal(4,2),
  expence decimal(4,2),
  PRIMARY KEY(documment_id)
);
```

I try this one using different method.but i'm unable to create trigger which is execute annually.most of the documents describes execute event annually.not the trigger.but I need a trigger.

Can someone help to me..

Comment: Triggers are fired by database events, not by clock events.

Comment: @McNets in my university assignment question have "Create e trigger annually and updates profit."

Comment: If this is homework, and you absolutely have to use triggers, then you need to consider what fires a trigger.  (btw, "create a trigger annually" is bizarre, and probably a translation issue; is the question actually "fire a trigger annually"?)  Anyway, a terrible solution to a convoluted spec is to create an event that does some db action in a given table periodically, that action fires the trigger, which runs the code.  Thus, you use a clock-based event to cause a table event that can fire the trigger. In the real world, go with @0xFFFFFF's answer.

Comment: Just use events, if the assignment is for MySQL. Even the MySQL docs state: *"Scheduled tasks of this type are also sometimes known as **“temporal triggers”**, implying that these are objects that are triggered by the passage of time."*

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ That's correct. I accept your answer.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may what you are looking for:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 year 
DO
  call dd
```

where `dd` is a PROCEDURE  written in it a code to create a trigger...

Comment: As I'm understanding, it says "Create e trigger annually and updates profit." does't mention the trigger should create by a trigger.  it is about creating a trigger automatically each year, whatever the way. @McNets